# cq:component vs normal component in aem

Tags: components, aem

I want to know what is the difference between if we make a component without cq: component property and with cq: component property in aem . I am new in aem so correct me if i am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have posted my answer but kindly read the AEM documentation to know more about it. https://helpx.adobe.com/support/experience-manager/6-5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cq:primarytype is like data that you use in java, which basically define the type of node. and cq:component is like type there are many type of node available in aem on which we works so by defining cq:component use defines that node is component type. for more information have a look [what is aem](https://www.aemhelper.com/aem-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all how can you make a component without cq:component? cq:component is the primary type of a node that you want to act as a component. If you dont declare a node as cq:component then basically its not a component and you cannot reuse it in any other of the page. You can think jcr:primary types as the data types used in java or any other programming language.

Hope this clears the doubt!!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, cq:Component is the jcr:primaryType of a Component.
jcr:primaryType is the type of the node you are creating, in your case, a component.
By default a node has the jcr:primaryType nt:unstructured, and if you want to change it to give more specific functionality, like a component, template, clientlibrary, you have options to do so.